# Date_Trunc not function working as expected

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to use the Date_Trunc for MONTH function in a SQL statement but somehow it is not working for me. I am trying to pull entries which happen after April 1st, 2019. The raw date format from the Redshift database is this format which I am trying to group into month/year buckets: **2019-04-08T00:13:20.000Z**

Input

```
SELECT
    client_id as user_id,
    session_utc as job_date --(format:2019-04-08T00:13:20.000Z)
    FROM  table1 as hits
    WHERE job_date >= DATE_TRUNC('month', 2019-04-01) 
    group by 1,2;
```

Output

```
"ERROR: function date_trunc("unknown", integer) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts."
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [DATE_TRUNC Function - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATE_TRUNC.html) takes *timestamp* as input and provides a *timestamp* as output:

```
DATE_TRUNC('datepart', timestamp)
```

For example:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('month', '2019-05-07'::timestamp)

2019-05-01 00:00:00
```

Therefore, your line should read:

```
WHERE job_date >= DATE_TRUNC('month', '2019-04-01'::timestamp)
```

If you wish to have the output as a date, append `::date`:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('month', '2019-05-07'::timestamp)::date

2019-05-01
```

Also, note that the *date* converts into a *timestamp* as at midnight. This can cause a difference for some comparisons. For example:

```
'2019-05-07 03:03:31.389324+00'::timestamp > '2019-05-07'::timestamp
```

will evaluate as `True` because it is comparing to midnight at the start of the day. This is different to comparing two dates (without timestamps).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Postgres, you need quotes around your date constant and can convert to the right types:

```
WHERE job_date >= DATE_TRUNC('month'::text, '2019-04-01'::date)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=a3ed46c51fa00482da39ac30f02b952b) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Not working either. Error:: function date_trunc("unknown", "unknown") is not unique Hint

Comment: still error: Invalid digit, Value '-', Pos 4, Type: Decimal code: 1207 context: 2019-04

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for the function is `DATE_TRUNC('datepart', timestamp)`, seems you need to use as `DATE_TRUNC('month', session_utc)`(*this already truncates to the first date of `April 2019` i.e.* `2019-04-01` )

Comment: is "datepart' the actual value or do I need to fill this variable?

Comment: @Tina excuse me, I forgot the literal there. Should be `month`.